# NSTableView with source, leads to EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist, exc-bad-access, nstableview

Although I find myself familiar with a bunch of programming languages, I fail for some time now to get used to Cocoa/Objective-C.

I wanted to fill a NSTableView with some content, with the following code:

```
- (int) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView {
return (int)[settingsPlist count];}

- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(int)rowIndex {
    NSString *title = [[NSString stringWithString:[[aTableColumn headerCell] stringValue]] autorelease];
    NSLog(title); // debug
    NSLog(@"%i",rowIndex); // debug
    if([title isEqual: @"Plugin Name"]) {
        return [[settingsPlist objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",rowIndex]] objectForKey:@"name"];
    } else {
        return @"(n/a)";
    }
}
```

*settingsPlist* is filled with the contents of a plist, looks like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>0</key>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Test-Plugin</string>
        <key>version</key>
        <string>0.1</string>
        <key>type</key>
        <string>Car</string>
        <key>creator</key>
        <string>Icke</string>
        <key>checksum</key>
        <string>0x32</string>
        <key>link</key>
        <string>http://</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The problem: It **works fine for one row** (you can tell by looking at the console output, thrown up by `NSLog(title);` and `NSLog(rowIndex);`), however, after that, the **debugger halts the execution, throwing up EXC_BAD_ACCESS**. I know what that means, but I don't know why I'm getting this and how to fix this.

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Do you know what ARC is, and why aren't you using it?  Objective-C may have already solved this problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did over release here,

```
    NSString *title = [[NSString stringWithString:[[aTableColumn headerCell] stringValue]] autorelease];
```

`-[NSString stringWithString:]` already autorelease the returned value, so you didn't need to call it again.